# Identify conflicting regular expressions

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql

I'm developing a small project with Ruby on Rails framework / PostgreSQL as DB, and I need to store some regular expressions in a table, like this:

```
------------------------
pattern       direction
-----------------------
1\d{3}        client1        
2\d{3}        client2
31\d{2}       client3
32\d{2}       client4
4             client5
-----------------------
```

Every pattern will start with one or more certain digits, and continued by an "unknown" digits (from 0 to 255 additional digits).

People will add new pairs to this table via GUI, and I'd like to avoid intersection, so for my example 3\d{3} should be not allowed to add, because it does intersect with 31\d{2} and 32\d{2}.

Is it possible to check existing expressions for intersection before adding new one to DB table?

Also, in GUI users will see these patterns like 1XXX, 2XXX, 31XX. I don't like to show them expressions. Maybe I don't have to use regexps at all? But I will need to search best matching pattern by certain number, for example, query with number 3291 should return me "client4", query "4" should return "client5".

What is the best practice in my case?

Comment: How many "unknown" are allowed in the pattern (max.)?

Comment: 255 in ideal case, but can be lowered till at least 30.

Comment: OK, with that many I would stick to your current storage method and translate `32\d{2}` to `32XX` on input / output. I also have an idea for your question ...

Comment: Yes, I was going to do translate from XXXX patterns to regexps on save/read from DB... it will be more comfortable for users.

Comment: Phone number prefix matching?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, it's a phone numbers.

Comment: @JC Ha, I thought so. Prefix routing. IIRC it's actually a hard problem (in the mathematical sense of hard) to do this efficiently, and there's a lot of literature out there about it.

Comment: @CraigRinger Well, yes, it's a part of my project, to find one unique route for certain prefix and give it to phone switch engine. But if you can provide titles of this special literature, as examples, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, disallow a new entry when:

- the total length matches.
- the prefix is a substring of an entry or vice versa.

You might store the total length redundantly or calculate it on the fly. I encapsulated the formula in a simple SQL function, based on the pattern displayed in the question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_pattern_len(text)
  RETURNS int AS
$$
SELECT COALESCE(substring($1, '(\d*)}$')::int, 0) -- digits in prefix
       + length(substring($1, '^\d*'))            -- digits in pattern
$$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Then, on `INSERT`, check like this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (pattern, direction)
SELECT i.input, 'client66'::text
FROM  (SELECT '3\d{7}'::text AS input) i
LEFT   JOIN tbl t
    ON f_pattern_len(t.pattern) = f_pattern_len(i.input)
   AND (substring(t.pattern, '^\d*') LIKE (substring(i.input, '^\d*') || '%') OR
        substring(i.input, '^\d*') LIKE (substring(t.pattern, '^\d*') || '%'))
WHERE t.pattern IS NULL
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/095eb/6)

You also can put the logic into a trigger `BEFORE INSERT` ...

Comment: Hmmm.. your solution looks very interesting, but I don't understand some moments at output on SQL Fiddle.. for example ,why for input 771\d{1} 1\d{3} pattern was defined as conflicting?

Comment: @JC: Oh, my bad. the `LIKE` pattern must be left anchored. I had a leading `%`, which spoiled the party. Should work now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll check all in my sandbox environment, but I think that your solution will do the trick.